# Surface Area of Rectangular Block

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

A solid rectangular block has a base which measures $2x$ cm by $x$ cm. The height of the block is $y$ cm
and the volume of the block is $72 cm^3$. Express $y$ in terms of $x$ and show that the total surface area, $Acm^2$
, of the block is given by $$A=4x^2+\frac{216}{x}$$

My attempt,

$2x^2y=72$

$y=\frac{36}{x^2}$

$A=2\cdot2x^2+4yx$

$A=4x^2+\frac{144}{x}$

Where have I done mistake?

Comment: In your area calculation, you're missing two sides.  You've got the $(x\times 2x)$ sides, the $(2x\times y)$ sides, but you're missing the $(x\times y)$ sides.

Comment: I got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, volume of the rectangular block $$V=\text{(length)}\times \text{(width)}\times \text{(height)}$$
$$(2x)(x)(y)=72$$
$$2x^2y=72$$$$\implies \color{blue}{y=\frac{36}{x^2}}$$
Now, the surface area of the rectangular block $$A=2(\text{(length)}\times \text{(width)}+\text{(length)}\times \text{(height)}+\text{(width)}\times \text{(height)})$$
$$=2(2x\cdot x+2x\cdot y+x\cdot y)$$
$$=4x^2+6xy$$ setting the values of $y$, one should get $$A=4x^2+6x\frac{36}{x^2}$$
$$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{A=4x^2+\frac{216}{x}}}$$

Comment: You always produce great answers with great explanation. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

The surface area is:

$$A = 2*(2x^2 + 2xy + xy) = 4x^2 + 6xy= 4x^2 + \frac{216}{x}$$

Answer (score 1):

Total surface area =$2(2x^2+3xy)$ so now $y=36/x^2$ so plugging in values you get $4x^2+\frac{108}{x^2}.2=4x^2+216/x^2$ you have missed $bh,lh$. Hope its clear now.